# ASP.Net Dynamic Excel Creation from SQL Datasource

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel, t-sql, crystal-reports

I want to create a dynamic excel worksheet that the client could download from the server, the data is on a SQL Server Database that I will get by a query like

```
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

I want to do something like Crystal Reports but in an Excel File

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities. One is to use DTS and Export wizard. You could read more on http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926. The code will be something like:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') SELECT * FROM employee
```

Second way: you could try with [EEPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) for creating Excel 2007 files.